# Does de Broglie equation give the exact/true wavelength of electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, electrons

Im talking about the de Broglie equation-

wavelength $\lambda =\frac{ h} {p}$

I studied a bit about Davisson-Germer experiment that provided conclusive evidence for wave nature of electrons and more importantly their results corresponded with de broglie equation.

Now, experimentally measured values may fluctuate but values given by mathematical equations are concrete,exact and accurate.

So, when we find the wavelength of electrons by plugging in its momentum in de broglie equation, we get a certain fixed value.

Is this THE exact wavelength of the electron?

Or what I really want to ask is that,

Is the de Broglie equation accurate (or our current best mathematical equation) to get the wavelength associated with an electron?

Or, Are there more developed theories and equations that give a better/correct wavelength of electrons?

Answer (score 3):

[The de Broglie equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#De_Broglie_relations)   equations relate the wavelength λ to the momentum p, and frequency f to the total energy E of a **free particle**

In present day mainstream physics the electron is an elementary point particle described with the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) with the mass and other attributes shown in the table. As such, its wave nature is modeled quantum mechanically, by the wavefunction which is the solution of the appropriate equation for the boundary conditions of the observation.

All the historical principles, laws , as the de Broglie,  confirmed observations can be shown mathematically to be derived by the quantum field theory presently used to study particles. One has to keep in mind that the collective "wave nature" described  before quantum mechanical theory evolved are not for individual particles, as the electron in your question. The wave nature of particles is seen in the accumulation of data , in probability distributions given by  the value of the wavefunction's  $Ψ{^*}Ψ$ . Single electrons have a probability to be at an (x,y,z,t) point , given by this. See this [single electron at a time simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) to get a feeling.

[image: dbl slit sim]

Here are the [original](https://www.hitachi.com/rd/research/materials/quantum/doubleslit/index.html) plots shown before somebody put in the simulation in wikipedia

[image: tonomura]

Comment: WOW! This single electron experiment totally changed the way I have been understanding quantum mechanics. All those wave functions make sense now. The need of quantum mechanics makes sense now.

Comment: I have been very confused about what the probability functions have to do to with all these interference patterns we see. I always thought that interference experiment showed the 'wave' nature of light. But, it shows the particle nature as well. FANTASTIC!

Comment: To be precise, the animation as a computer simulation and not an experiment.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler  You are correct, I have edited. I had used that link before they changed it.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler True. But it shouldn't be lost in the message that an experiment would see the same sort of buildup of points.